# Kernel Died when using Kmeans with a big data frame

Tags: python

I am trying to use Kmeans in Python with a data frame(Scaled_pca) with  shape (78544,700), and the Kernel always died.
the below is my code:

```
centers = []
score = []
for i in range(20):
    kmean = KMeans(i+1)
    model = kmean.fit(Scaled_pca)
    centers.append(i+1)
    score.append(abs(model.score(Scaled_pca)))
```

Comment: i am also having same issue

Comment: Can you monitor memory consumption? Maybe you are just running out of memory? On Linux you could also check the output of `dmesg` to see whether a process got killed because of using too much memory.

Comment: yes, I am running out of memory, the usage of memory reached 99%

Comment: It may be expected behavior then. Reducing the input data size or installing more memory might help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a conundrum for sure....no guaranty that this will work, a lot depends on how much you have drifting in memory and how frugal you are in your code. I would do four things. Only one of them is code-based.

1. close everything except the browser you use for Jupyter (no other applications open)
2. close all tabs other than the notebook, and clear your cookies and cache
3. Look in the `Running` tab of Jupyter and close all but this one notebook
4. Build into your code some methods for reclaiming memory. Start by adding `del old_variable` for everything in your notebook you have used that you do not need, or can rebuild after this runs to free up real estate for the kernel. Then build deletion and garbage collection into your loops.

   ```
   import gc 
   # I would use a delete everything here 
   gc.collect()

   centers = []
   score = []
   for i in range(20):
       kmean = KMeans(i+1)
       model = kmean.fit(Scaled_pca)
       centers.append(i+1)
       score.append(abs(model.score(Scaled_pca)))
       del kmean #removes old instance
       del model #removes old model
       gc.collect() #garbage collects all orphaned and unused stuff
   ```

This may not completely solve your problem, but it can get you headed in the right direction.

The other thing you might consider, because Jupyter is NOT efficient by hazard of its JavaScript to Python to JavaScript nature, is running this script in something more efficient, command line even (after testing your code on say 100 line of data) and saving the results AND models into `pickle` then bringing them back into the notebook.

You can always include the appropriate code in the notebook if you need to show if for work or academic reasons, just do not execute that cell.

I have found that many things which stall in Jupyter fly seamlessly in a text-based IDE.

Comment: Actually, I have tried to reduce the size of the dataset by reducing the number of Columns and it is ok